Hang after S3 resume - Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0xfc1e failed: -16
I have an MSI board with built in Intel AX200 BT and Wifi. This is on
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:29:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

After successfully booting Ubuntu 24.04 running 6.8.0-31-generic, I can see this entry in dmesg:
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0xfc1e failed: -16

Bluetooth is operational with no apparent issues.
When I suspend (s3) and then resume, I get a black console screen with a single line - another example of the above error, keyboard is unresponsive e.g. to ctrl-alt-f1 . The only recourse is a hard power cycle.
Dmesg after resume:
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported. 
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Battery Provider Manager created
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0xfc1e failed: -16
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: src/device.c:device_set_wake_support() Unable to set wake_support without RPA resolution
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x45
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: src/device.c:device_set_wake_support() Unable to set wake_support without RPA resolution
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: input: Logitech MX Master as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/0003:046D:4071.0009/input/input32
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4071.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech MX Master] on usb-0000:02:00.0-6/input2:1
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: r8169 0000:2a:00.0 enp42s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
<timestamp> ubu-desktop suspend: nvidia-resume.service
<timestamp> ubu-desktop logger[7939]: <13>May 24 09:10:47 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: r8169 0000:2a:00.0 enp42s0: Link is Down
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-0-2a00:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-2a00:00, irq=MAC)
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: usb 6-3: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: r8169 0000:2a:00.0 enp42s0: Link is Down
<timestamp> ubu-desktop kernel: usb 6-3: current rate 16000 is different from the runtime rate 48000
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
<timestamp> ubu-desktop bluetoothd[1600]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.153 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex
<timestamp> ubu-desktop gsd-media-keys[4088]: Unable to get default sink

Other posts around the internet suggest this might be related to the combination of Nvidia GPU with AX200 radio, but it's not conclusive. The post-resume hang issue has only appeared since upgrading from Ubuntu 23.10 - unsure of that kernel version, however I remember seeing the "Opcode 0xfc1e failed" error in dmesg back then.
Has anyone else seen this? Not sure what to try

Did you ever figure this out?
